# How to remove a mesh of an object3D from scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to remove some part/mesh ('olympiaPart2' for example) of this object3D :

```
Object3D {uuid: "78E3A86E-3AF3-4C0F-8805-DE8531F3D512", name: "circle3D", type: "Object3D", parent: Scene, children: Array(1), …}
    castShadow: false
    children: Array(1)
        0: Scene
        autoUpdate: true
        background: null
        castShadow: false
        children: Array(8)
            0: Mesh {uuid: "812FC68F-1421-4C9F-92A9-68D969E955F3", name: "olympiaPart0", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            1: Mesh {uuid: "DF3A40D8-5449-4480-88C3-DDBC2EC5FDAB", name: "olympiaPart1", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
-->         2: Mesh {uuid: "80C9467C-95E8-460D-844F-57F37673F745", name: "olympiaPart2", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            3: Mesh {uuid: "12C8660E-80B3-4FBC-BC0B-C72C8AAD8355", name: "olympiaPart3", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            4: Mesh {uuid: "1851A94E-5D8F-4A87-B66C-E1B2C7706B36", name: "olympiaPart4", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            5: Mesh {uuid: "BA629A09-AB2E-499F-AAE0-17A3FB2B18C1", name: "olympiaPart5", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            6: Mesh {uuid: "8D014976-92A5-4290-A876-77F27375EFD8", name: "olympiaPart6", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            7: Mesh {uuid: "3B656568-0C4C-4C69-AE80-7A76E29C496E", name: "olympiaPart7", type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
            length: 8
```

I'm not sure on how to proceed, but I already tryied this :

```
scene.remove( circle3D.children[0].getObjectByName('olympiaPart2') )
```

and

```
const removePart = circle3D.getObjectByName('olympiaPart2')
scene.remove(removePart)
```

Nothing is changed even if I console.log my scene or object3D.
No error is returned, nothing changes on screen.

This is how my object3D is created :

```
// Circle
const circle3D = new THREE.Object3D
circle3D.name = 'circle3D'
scene.add(circle3D)

const importModel = (_model) => {
    // I use gltf-loader from : www.npmjs.com/package/three-gltf-loader
    let modelLoader = new GLTFLoader()

    modelLoader.load(
        _model,
        ( gltf ) => {
            gltf.scene.rotation.x = 270 * Math.PI / 180

            // Name each mesh to control them
            for(let i=0; i<gltf.scene.children.length; i++) {
                gltf.scene.children[i].name = `olympiaPart${i}`
            }

            // Append to circle3D object
            circle3D.add(gltf.scene)
        }
    )
}

// olympia is the gltf model I import with webpack
importModel(olympia)
//
```

The expected result would be that some parts/meshes of my object3D disappear after a certain delay/event like timeout or click.
I'm aware that my problem must have some link about updating the object or scene, but honestly I feel like I've try every options I could imagine.

Here is my loop function just in case :

```
loop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)

    // Renderer & Update
    // Render is handling other animations already implemented (rotations & easing for others objects)
    update()
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the mesh from its parent, not from the `scene` itself. Try this:

```
const removePart = circle3D.getObjectByName('olympiaPart2');
const parent = removePart.parent;
parent.remove( removePart );
```

`three.js R107`

Comment: Thanks, I did not understood how this object3D was exactly working.
Now I understand and it's working !